# sync version of ProtectedLocalStorage/ProtectedSessionStorage for server side

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm migrating a legacy application that was previously using one SessionState class to track the session variables. Now I changed it with `ProtectedLocalStorage/ProtectedSessionStorage` to keep the state. But I need some sync methods to get/set in storage.

While I'm using `protectedLocalStorage.getAsync(key).getAwaiter().getResult()` (it's not good, but i want min effort to run the application). But this solution isn't working, the task is never complete.

Blazor webassembly has sync versions but for server-side options are not available.

Please suggest any solution where I could get and set sync.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong end of the problem. Why do (you think) you need sync versions?

Comment: because I have created a custom class having synchronous GetSession and SetSession and injecting `ProtectedBrowserStorage` to implement these methods. It's a legacy project where we are migrating to Blazor. They have used static class using with HttpContext sessions everywhere. we are just replacing these sessions to sessionstorage.

Comment: That will propagate a bad practice up to the rest of your code. The Web (Browser) is async.